# What's wrong with this PDO 'Month... Between' Query?

Tags: mysql, pdo

```
('SELECT id,username,tag,message,timestamp FROM mybq_txt where id = ? AND (MONTH('date') BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()')));
```

I'm trying to select content within the last month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use back ticks instead of single quote:

```
.... AND (MONTH(`date`) BETWEEN ....
                ^here
```

But I don't think you have to use `MONTH` function, just use date between the date range.

The query should be:

```
SELECT id,username,tag,message,timestamp 
FROM mybq_txt where id = ? 
AND `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
```